# nginx rewrite condition only for root folder (not for subfolders)

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, nginx

I'm using nginx infront of apache for static content serving. I have a rewrite rule, which redirects all missing php files to specific (index.php) file. But currently that rule applies everywhere in the root folder (including subdirectories). I want to make it working only for / directory and not subdirectories. For example if I access http://www.domain.com/someting/missing.php I want to get 404 code. But if I access http://www.domain.com/missing.php still to get index.php
Here is my code so far :

```
location ~ \.php$ {
proxy_pass http://ip:7777;
proxy_set_header Host             $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Accel-Internal /internal-nginx-static-location;
access_log off;
try_files $uri @missing;
}

location @missing {
 rewrite ^ /index.php last;
}
```

Comment: Come on guys, anything at all? Any suggestion will do!